# Loading WMS layers from Geoserver into QGIS using env-parameter to style?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I have a layer with a SLD-style on my Geoserver that requires a date through the "env"-parameter, which works fine in the OpenLayers application where the style will finally be used. However, it'd be great to be able to inspect the style in QGIS, just by importing the WMS layer and passing an "env"-parameter with the WMS request to Geoserver.

Unfortunately, I can't find any such options to pass additional parameters in the QGIS add WMS-tool. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?